# how to prevent overriding while retrieving node property from AEM in jsp page?

Tags: jsp, aem

i have created JSP page in aem and drag and drop 2 same component from parsys. in jsp i am retrieving the value onclick on component one of those. but every time i got the value of last one. property value is overriding. anyone can help me?

```
<%@include file="/libs/foundation/global.jsp"%>
<html>

<head>
    <title>Link Components</title>
</head>
<script>
    var link;

    function openWindow() {
        link = "<%=properties.get(". / linkpage ")%>";
        alert(link);
        window.open("<%=properties.get(". / link ")%>");
        hyperlink = "<%=properties.get(". / link ")%>"
    }
</script>

<body>
    <a href="#" onclick="javascript:openWindow();">
        <%=properties.get("./link‌​page")%>
    </a>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Can you please show some code?

Comment: `function openWindow()` is in global namespace, so the second component inclusion overrides the function definition.

Comment: so exactly what should i do?

Comment: @PriyankDave encapsulate your front-end code. The code in your snippet will be executed every time you render a component. A better way to organise it would be to place your JS code in a client library. You could then use the [Module pattern](http://www.adequatelygood.com/JavaScript-Module-Pattern-In-Depth.html) to read the relevant information from the component markup (from a data attribute for example).

Answer (score 0):

AEM is a server side component based architecture.

When you're creating a component, think of it as a reusable snippet of code that can be customized by the parameters that you put in.

Since you put two component on the same page everything will be on that page at the same level. As mentioned, that's why you're getting the overwrite.

So to improve your code, first take out anything "page" related and focus on what's needed just for you're component.

```
<script>
    var link;

    function openWindow() {
        link = "<%=properties.get(". / linkpage ")%>";
        alert(link);
        window.open("<%=properties.get(". / link ")%>");
        hyperlink = "<%=properties.get(". / link ")%>"
    }
</script>

<a href="#" onclick="javascript:openWindow();">
    <%=properties.get("./link‌​page")%>
</a>
```

You don't need a title or body, because you should be dropping these components into a parsys on a page that already has those.

There are multiple ways of modifying the script to be unique per component an example would be to pass in a parameter

```
<script>
    var link;

    function openWindow(foo) {
        link = "<%=properties.get(". / linkpage ")%>";
        alert(foo);
        window.open(foo);
        hyperlink = foo
    }
</script>

<a href="#" onclick="javascript:openWindow('<%=properties.get("./link‌​page")%>');">
    <%=properties.get("./link‌​page")%>
</a>
```

That's overkill for what you are specifically trying to do here. Which you could just implement as

```
<a href='<%=properties.get("./link‌​page")%>' target='_blank'><%=properties.get("./link‌​page")%>
</a>
```